# Get Properties of Object, but not of Parent Object

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have 2 Classes:

```
export class A extends B {
  private prop1: string;
  private prop2: string;
  constructor() {
    this.prop1 = "A";
    this.prop2 = "A";
  }
}

export abstract class B {
  private prop3: "B";
  constructor() {
    this.prop3 = "B";
  }
}

let a = new A();
let b = new B();
```

If I now do `Object.getOwnProperties(a)`
I also get the properties of the inherited class `b`.
--> `prop1, prop2, prop3`

Ist there any way to ONLY get `prop1` and `prop2`, and omit `prop3` as it is only an inherited property?

I know that Object.getOwnProperties(a) is the wrong approach, but is there any other approach I can go to ONLY get the properties of the baseClass, and not it`s inherited class also?

Comment: What is `abstract class` and `prop3: "B"`? That's not valid JS syntax.

Comment: The thing is, there's only one object involved, and it has the "own" properties that it has.  At runtime, there's no distinction made about when a property was added to an object.

Comment: @Bergi Now its valid, but I think it was OK to get the idea of what I wanted to do with only the pseudocode aswell...

Comment: @DigitalJedi Now it's still not valid JS code - please tag your question as TS if that's what you are using :-)

Comment: @Bergi there you go

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible (other than hardcoding the names of the properties that you want to get).

Those are instance properties, not prototypically inherited properties. `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3` are indistinguishable at runtime, they are all own properties of the object itself. It does not make a difference which constructor created them on the instance.

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the properties of the abstract class? With that I could remove them from all properties and be left with the properties I want...

Comment: You could call `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` right after the `super()` call, before creating your own properties. Or from the outside, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new B)`, but for that you need to ignore TS errors and ensure that abstract class can actually be instantiated (ideally without side effects).

Comment: @DigitalJedi What is your actual goal and what parts of the code are you able to modify?

Comment: I have many classes extending another class (B in the example). My goal is to "check" the properties of all the classes that extend this one class B. But I do not want to check the properties specified in class B... Maybe I just have to exclude the properties I do not want manually (e.g. check if a property in Object.getOwnProperties(a) is also in b and then exclude it...

Comment: "Check" where and for what? But yeah, it's probably the simplest to just manually exclude them if there's only one parent class and it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

When you are extending a class you are calling the parent constructor by passing the child object as the "this" object. So if you set properties in the parent class you are automatically setting them in the child class too.

```
class Parent {
   constructor() {
       this.parentProp = "A";
   }
}
class Child extends Parent {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.childProp = "B";
   }
}
```

under the hood, they would behave like this:

```
function Parent() {
   this.parentProp = "A";
}

function Child() {
   //...
   //some prototype manipulation here to make Child extend Parent
   //...
   Parent.apply(this, arguments); //this calls the Parent function with "this" being the child object
   this.childProp = "B";
}

new Child() // {parentProp: "A", childProp: "B"}
```